# Ubuntu As Default OS

Tags: boot

I have a Dell Insiron laptop, which currently runs windows. There is a a logo of Ubuntu on my computer, I dont know why. Can anyone tell me why that is?

And I have downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu from your website.  Now I want to delete Windows and install Ubuntu as the permanent operating system, without other Grub loader type of things, just like windows - which loads like normal. Please give me guidance about that, and I don't want to delete any personal data.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to grab the iso file on a disk and boot on it !
After choosing "try ubuntu without install", you will be able to access your Windows datas and backup on an exteranl drive.

Grub will be installed by default, but while you have just 1 OS il will not prompt you at boot time...

Answer (score 0):

How many GBs of data do you have? If you don't have more than 10 GB, then upload them in Google Drive, than mount the iso file (that you download at Ubuntu.com) on a disk, or you can put it in an USB, then when you boot with disk (or USB), format the hard disk, then install the ubuntu.

Comment: i have got more than 300 Gbs of data :(